# "Cheer" for a team?

Tags: vocabulary

Here I am again to ask a question about a vocabulary item.

What word is used to describe yourself as the fan of a team, that you support it, cheer for it and want it to win ?

If I say, "I am cheering for the Czech team" it doesn't sound good English. So what should I say?

Many thanks in advance for your contribution.

Mel.

Comment: "Cheering for X" is a perfectly valid use of the word. There is also "rooting for X", which implies a more general form of support that may not necessarily have the physical "cheering" aspect.

Comment: 'Rooting' for a team is an American expression. No one in Britain can understand it, nor what 'rooting' has to do with cheering, supporting, or being a fan.

Comment: "Pulling for" a team is also common in the States.

Comment: @WS2 Good point. In Britain, that would be a much more "hands-on" kind of support. ;)

Comment: @WS2, did the OP ask for Brit-only expressions?  "Rooting" is not only common in the US but is used in the famous baseball song, "Take Me Out to the Ball Game".  **"...so it's root, root root for the home team, if they don't win it's a shame..."**

Comment: @KristinaLopez But what is the origin of 'root', in this context? I know what a root is? I know of a verb 'to root' which is something (and I'm giving away my rural upbringing) that pigs do when you put them out in a field. They burrow away at the roots of plants.  You can also 'root' yourself to the spot. You can 'root' plants. And at the obscene end of things in Ireland, Australia and New Zealand, to'root' is a vulgar expression for having sexual intercourse.  But what has 'root' got to do with cheering for a team?

Comment: @WS2, the definition of the transitive verb "root" is: *to noisily applaud or encourage a contestant or team.*   Synonymous with "cheer"  (Per Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary which cites unknown origin - perhaps alteration of *"rout"*)  First known use: 1889.

Comment: The verb _root_ in this sense is always pronounced /ru:t/ in the US, even in areas where the verb _root_, describing what pigs do, is pronounced /rʊt/. I'd say they were separate lexical items.

Comment: @KristinaLopez It is in the OED as meaning 4, and it confirms the first use as 1889. It lists it as a 'colloquialism - orig. slang'.

Comment: @KristinaLopez But the interesting thing is the definition of 'rout', per New Shorter Oxford Dict. 'rout'- v.intrans. chiefly Scotland and north, of a cow - bellow, roar, low...of a person - roar or cry loudly. v.trans. Utter in a roar, shout. This probably explains John Lawler's point about the pronunciation being different to the other 'root'. They are not 'rooting' but 'routing' - i.e. bellowing like cows!

Comment: @JohnLawler Seems like it is 'rout', which confirms your point about 'a separate lexical item'.

Comment: @WS2, yup, bellowing like cows but keeping our hooves to ourselves. :-p. And to be clear, since I'm not a wiz with the pronunciation symbols, it's pronounced like boot, not like lout.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - It needs to be noted that the guy who wrote "Take Me Out to the Ball Game" had never attended a baseball game.

Comment: @HotLicks  - maybe that's why he wrote the song...he was asking to be taken to a ball game!  (How sad, right?) :'-(

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a British response.

I support Norwich City. I am a fan of Norwich City. I am a Norwich City supporter. When I go to a match, I cheer for Norwich City. Norwich City are my team. I am a follower of Norwich City. In fact I see the world through yellow and green tinted spectacles! I see little yellow birds in my dreams. The Canaries are my life.

Answer (score 0):

cheer

> A [**cheer**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cheer) is what you shout at a sporting event when you cheer
>   your team on, showing your enthusiasm and support. Often there's a lot
>   of cheer or good spirits at these games, unless of course your
>   favorite team loses.

Your sentence:

"I am **cheering** for the Czech team"

is good English usage and sounds very good too!